# Как изменить стиль третьего элемента при помощи :checked?

Tags: css3, html5

Как, при помощи *:checked* (`#second_button:checked`), изменить фон *div*-a, в котором находится данный *checkbox* (`#buttons`), используя только HTML и CSS?

Пробовала сделать так, как ниже - не работает. Спасибо всем за помощь)

```css
#buttons {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

#buttons label {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

label[for="second_button"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#second_button:checked~#buttons {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="first_button">
    <label for="first_button">I can change the background-color</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="second_button">
    <label for="second_button">I can make headline disappear</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Без скриптов такое пока невозможно. Потомки не могут влиять на родителя (за редким исключением).

Answer (score 2):

При той разметке, которая представлена в вопросе, организовать требуемое поведение невозможно (пока не ввели в CSS псевдокласс `:has()`).

Можно приблизительно имитировать логику, если разместить *input*-ы перед *div*-ом, но это жутко неправильно, и делать так я не советую:

```css
#buttons {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

#buttons label {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

label[for="second_button"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#first_button:checked~#buttons {
  background-color: red;
}
#second_button:checked~#buttons {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="first_button">
<input type="checkbox" id="second_button">
<div id="buttons">
  <div>
    <label for="first_button">I can change the background-color</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="second_button">I can make headline disappear</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот ещё один способ сделать это, но тоже извращённый.

```css
#buttons {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

#buttons label {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

label[for="second_button"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#first_button:checked + .bg {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: red;
}

#second_button:checked + .bg {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="first_button">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <label for="first_button">I can change the background-color</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="second_button">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <label for="second_button">I can make headline disappear</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: По-любому, только скриптами. Когда уже утвердят этот `:has()` ?.. :-(

Comment: @UModeL кто их знает. Видимо есть какие-то причины типа производительности или "много переделывать".

Comment: именно из-за производительности, но можно же хотя бы на один уровень сделать. Тем более, что в `querySelector()`, этот селектор поддерживался какое-то время. Эх, мЯчты...

Comment: @UModeL ну если так, то моё мнение что "программер" должен решать, хоть весь браузер колом станет если нужно ради смены фона. Можно вечный цикл написать и повесить всё, а тут какая-то производительность стала важна. Хотя это скорее диванные эмоции.

Comment: вот! Полностью поддерживаю.